# Prove: If $a > b$ then $\arctan a$ > $\arctan b$.

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

No idea how to do this. Even just some intuition would help.

Comment: arctan is monotone

Comment: Try just graphing the function

Comment: First derivative is positive.

Comment: Which definition of arctan are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)= \tan x$ is increasing on $(-{\pi\over 2},{\pi \over 2})$ so is it inverse function $f^{-1}(x)= {\rm arctan}\, x$ increasing.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d(\arctan x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}>0 $$

Hence, $\arctan{x} $ is monotonously increasing function.

Therefore, $a>b \implies \arctan a>\arctan b$

(Definition of monotonously increasing function : $x_1>x_2 \implies f( x_1) > f( x_2)$)